# Laravel/Sentry Assigning Group Permissions from Form

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to wrap my head around permissions and arrays in Sentry. I've got them working when I hardcode them, that's easy, but assigning them from a form is proving to be very... Frustrating to say the least. Here is the function that handles it:

```
public function postGroup(){
    $name = Input::get('name');
    $inputs = Input::except('name');
    $permissions = array("self.view" => 1, "self.update" => 1);
    foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
    {
        $raw_name = $key;
        $name = str_replace('_', '.', $raw_name);
        array_push($permissions, array($name => 1)); // The issue is here. 
    }
...
```

Basically, we now have an array `$permissions` with `[user.create] => 1, [user.view] => 1` etc etc for each permission passed from the Form. Next, using `Sentry::createGroup` I need to set the permissions based on this array.

```
//Create the group
        $group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
         'name'        => $name,
         'permissions' => $permissions //Doesn't work.
```

));

When I check my database, I see this:

```
{"self.view":1,"self.update":1,"0":1,"1":1}
```

It should be something like this:

```
{"self.view":1,"self.update":1,"user.create":1,"user.view":1}
```

So we can see the `self.*` ones work fine, but since I'm calling `array_push($permissions, array($name => 1));` I'm making `$permissions` a multidimensional array (Hence why we see `"0":1` in the database; it's looking at the index. But I'm not 100% sure how to fix this...

So, any insight into array handling and Sentry Permissions would be helpful. I'll keep trying in the meantime.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot... This is a really simple answer. Replace:

```
array_push($permissions, array($name => 1)); // The issue is here.
```

with (and I can't believe how simple this is)

```
$permissions[$name] = 1;
```

to avoid the multidimensional array issue. Le Sigh.